# System error 5 while setting up SQL server on share

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to setup a SQL server on a local share. I am doing this because it is too expensive at my organization to buy a SQL server. I followed steps from:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881455/sql-server-database-on-network-share`

this is being done on Microsoft SQL server

Now, when I write in SQL server management studio (2012)

```
xp_cmdshell 'net use I: \\ShareDriveLocation'
```

I get a System error 5 has occurred, like below:

> System error 5 has occurred. NULL. Access is denied. NULL. NULL

I have access to this share and I have even tried to map it on the work space I am working, still the same error.

I am working on a windows 7 machine and I connect to SQL server management studio with the name of my work space `(DVVDI1234\SQLEXPRESS)`

Comment: mysql <> sql server, please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what "setup a SQL server on a local share" means? Also, using a share, SQL server already *is* a shared server. The client never connect to the database files, they connect to the database engine and it is the database engine (only) who need access to the database files. Anyhow, if you try to created database files on a network drive make sure that you use UNC naming and that the SQL Server service account has permissions on that share.

Comment: Why install SQL Server on a *shared folder*? `it is too expensive at my organization to buy a SQL server. ` that doesn't make any sense. You obviously downloaded SQL Server Express. Besides, SQL Server Developer Edition is free. Install it on a *local* folder, not a share

Comment: The linked question shows how to create a *database* on a share, not install the server. If that's what you want to do make sure the SQL Server service account has permission to read/write on that share. On the other hand, IO is the most important bottleneck with databases and a *network share* will always be slower than a local disk

Comment: sorry all for my lack of knowledge. I have indeed installed it on my local system and create a database on the share.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise running SQL Server Management Studio as administrator.

The error suggests that the application doesn't have permission to do this.

Comment: I am still running into the same error, even after opening management studio as administrator. BTW, I got this command from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881455/sql-server-database-on-network-share